# Proof of $\left|\sum_{k=2}^n \lfloor k^{\varphi-1}\rfloor-B_n\right|\le 2$

Tags: calculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When I was trying approximate this sum $\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\left\lfloor k^{\varphi-1}\right\rfloor$, where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the golden-ratio, I found that
$B_n=\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^\varphi}{\varphi}+\dfrac{n^{\varphi-1}-n}{2}\right\rfloor$ is a good approximation $A_n$.
reference [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=table%5Bsum%5Bfloor%28k%5E%28goldenratio-1%29%29-1%2F%28n-1%29floor%28%28n%5Egoldenratio%29%2F%28goldenratio%29%2B%28n%5E%28goldenratio-1%29-n%29%2F%282%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C2%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C600%7D%5D)
Can you help me proving that $\left|A_n-B_n\right|\le 2$?

Comment: Heuristically,
$$\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left\lfloor {k^{\varphi  - 1} } \right\rfloor }  \approx \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {k^{\varphi  - 1}  - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}  = \frac{{n^\varphi  }}{\varphi } + \frac{{n^{\varphi  - 1}  - n}}{2} +\mathcal{O}(1).$$

Answer (score 2):

If you use, as @Gary suggested in comments,
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left\lfloor {k^{\phi  - 1} } \right\rfloor }  \approx \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {k^{\phi  - 1}  - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}=T_n  $$ then
$$T_n = H_n^{(1-\phi )}-\frac {n+1} 2$$ and, asymptotically,
$$H_n^{(1-\phi )}=n^{\phi -1} \left(\frac{n}{\phi }+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\phi-1 }{12
   n}-\frac{(3-\phi ) (2-\phi) (\phi -1)}{720 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)+\zeta(1-\phi )$$ and
$$\Delta_n=|S_n-T_n|$$ is quite small : for $2\leq n \leq 1000$, $\Delta_n^{\text{max}}=2.77$ while $S_{1000}=43706$.

Some numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & T_n & S_n \\
 10 & 23.0747 & 22 \\
 20 & 72.2587 & 71 \\
 30 & 141.157 & 140 \\
 40 & 226.888 & 226 \\
 50 & 327.692 & 327 \\
 60 & 442.338 & 442 \\
 70 & 569.894 & 569 \\
 80 & 709.625 & 709 \\
 90 & 860.926 & 861 \\
 100 & 1023.29 & 1024 \\
 200 & 3180.61 & 3182 \\
 300 & 6163.52 & 6163 \\
 400 & 9849.07 & 9850 \\
 500 & 14162.8 & 14163 \\
 600 & 19053.0 & 19052 \\
 700 & 24480.5 & 24481 \\
 800 & 30414.4 & 30415 \\
 900 & 36829.6 & 36828 \\
 1000 & 43704.7 & 43706 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Considering
$$T_n-\left(\dfrac{n^\phi}{\phi}+\dfrac{n^{\phi-1}-n}{2}-\frac 12\right)$$ it is asymptotic to
$$\zeta(1-\phi )+\frac{1}{12\phi} n^{-\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2} }$$

**Edit**

Counting
$$\Delta_n=\left|\sum_{k=2}^n k^{\varphi-1}-\left\lfloor \dfrac{n^\varphi}{\varphi}+\dfrac{n^{\varphi-1}-n}{2}\right\rfloor\right|$$ for $2\leq n \leq 10000$

- $3$ appears $1002$ times (starting at $n=954$)
- $4$ appears $594$ times (starting at $n=1806$)
- $5$ appears $756$ times (starting at $n=5372$)

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but i thing so $\Delta_{1000}\approx 1.3$,really?

Comment: @hxthanh. $2.77$ is the maximum absolute difference for $n\leq 1000$.

Comment: Wow! Therefore $\lfloor k^\varphi\rfloor \not\approx k^\varphi -1/2$
Also $|A_n-B_n|\le 2$ true or false?

Comment: @hxthanh. Let me check for a huge interval.

Comment: @hxthanh I never claimed that $\left\lfloor {k^{\varphi  - 1} } \right\rfloor  \approx k^{\varphi  - 1}  - \frac{1}{2}$. What I claimed that it is true on average: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left\lfloor {k^{\varphi  - 1} } \right\rfloor }  \approx \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {k^{\varphi  - 1}  - \frac{1}{2}} \right)} .
$$

Comment: @hxthanh. Bad news in my edit

Comment: Great work! But i thing so $$\sum_{k=2}^n k^{\varphi-1} \ne \sum_{k=2}^n \left\lfloor k^{\varphi-1} \right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 1):

Lower Riemann sum
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \phi \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\phi-1} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \int_0^1 \phi x^{\phi-1} = [x^{\phi}]_{0}^1 = 1$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \phi \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\phi-1} \approx n$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}  k^{\phi-1} \approx \frac{n^{\phi}}{\phi}$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}  k^{\phi-1} \approx \frac{n^{\phi}}{\phi} + n^{\phi-1}$$

Similarly you can get:
Upper Riemann sum
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \phi \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\phi-1} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \int_0^1 \phi x^{\phi-1} = [x^{\phi}]_{0}^1 = 1$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \phi \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{\phi-1} \approx n$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}  k^{\phi-1} \approx \frac{n^{\phi}}{\phi}$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}  k^{\phi-1} \approx \frac{n^{\phi}}{\phi} $$

Using the average of Upper Riemann sum and Lower Riemann sum based expressions we get
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}  k^{\phi-1} \approx \frac{n^{\phi}}{\phi} + n^{\phi-1}/2.$$

The approximation becomes accurage as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

The Error bound is $$\left|\frac{n^{\phi-1}}{\phi} \sum_{k=2}^n -n \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} \phi x^{\phi-1} + \phi(k/n)^{\phi-1} - n^{\phi-1}/2 \right|$$
$$ = \left| \frac{1}{\phi} \sum_{k=2}^n -k^{\phi}+(k-1)^{\phi}+ \phi k^{\phi-1} - n^{\phi-1}/2 \right|$$

By mean Value theorem,
for $h \in [k-1,k]$,
$$\leq \left|\frac{1}{\phi} \sum_{k=2}^n -\phi h^{\phi-1}+ \phi k^{\phi-1} - n^{\phi-1}/2 \right |$$
For $h' \in [k-1,k]$ and it turns out we can use $h-k \approx 1/2$,
$$\leq \left |\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\phi} \sum_{k=2}^n \phi  (\phi-1)h'^{\phi-2} - n^{\phi-1}/2 \right |$$
Note that $\phi- 2 <0 $,
$$\leq \left |\frac{1}{2} \times (\phi-1) \sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)^{\phi-2}  -  n^{\phi-1}/2. \right |$$
$$\leq \left|\frac{1}{2} (\phi-1) \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{\phi-2}  -  \frac{n^{\phi-1}}{(\phi-1)} \right) \right |$$

Approximately using $\phi-1 \approx 0.5$ and using $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$,
$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{\phi-2} \approx \frac{n^{\phi-1}}{\phi-1}$$
Error seems to be less.

See if above is useful. Good Luck!

Comment: I understand your proof, but the difference between $k^{\varphi-1}$ and $\lfloor k^{\varphi-1}\rfloor$ is relatively large resulting in a significantly reduced sum. Thanks for reply!